# 1-1/4 brass sink drain pipe stuck in larger cast iron elbow--threaded or not?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, sink, p-trap

Attempting to replace p-trap in bathroom, 1954 ranch on slab. There is a 1-1/4 brass drain pipe "stuck" into larger cast iron elbow in wall. The brass pipe is short, no longer perfectly round. I don't have much luck using union connector on it. So should I get it out, and how? If the iron fitting isn't threaded, then how do I add a replacement stub out?

The plumbing will be exposed under new wall mount sink, so would prefer to replace this copper drain pipe with new chromed copper pipe, but until then, any way to get this back to working order would be helpful.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a grotty mess, (old drain plumbing for ya) but it most likely is a slip fit coupling (but you'd have to excavate some of the rust and/or plaster(?) to get a sense of whether it IS, in fact that.) See this recent quesion to get a sense of what you're looking for in that grotty mess: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/239280/18078

Comment: Since you can access the back side replace the whole thing with plastic but you may have to add a vent, I cannot see one but it may be behind the wall out of site. Has the drain worked properly or was it slow, which would be an indicator of improper venting.

Comment: it looks soldered

Comment: @Jasen, If it is soldered, I think I'd need heat to get it out, but then is it likely that soldering the only option for securing a replacement in that elbow? Or is there a good chance there are usable threads?